# need some javascript for a pdf form

Tags: forms, pdf

not sure if I've come to the right place or not. Any help is appreciated.

I am creating a form that will post certain air quality test results on a building. Users will insert particular numbers in the form (e.g., concentration of certain gases, etc.). If number meets acceptable standards (e.g., below acceptable maximum), then I would like a check box to turn on that says the building meets the safety standards.

let A be air quality value
let B be maximum accepted value
let C be checkbox indicating pass

So, if A is less than B, then C is ON (pass) but if A is greater than B, C is OFF (fail)

Ideally, C will be a graphic of a green check mark or a red ex.

thx

Comment: Do you need this to work in any PDF viewer including in a browser or can you force the users to use Adobe Reader or other JavaScript-capable viewer?

Comment: @joelgeraci, I think it's fair to ask people to fill it out in Adobe Reader (or Acrobat Pro).

Comment: But can you enforce what viewer is used? If you can't, it's not worth adding the script. It won't work in ***most*** PDF viewers. Your users will need to know to download the file and open it in a JavaScript-capable reader.

Comment: Please don't concern yourself about that. I am confident we can get users to use Acrobat reader. Do you know if the js can be done?

Comment: It can be done but there's a bit of prep work to create the document in a way that you can swap out the graphics. See my answer and example file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set up a file with your field and 4 "buttons" set to read-only which are really just holders for your graphics. One is the visible button that has its image replaced by the code, three of them are hidden, the check, the X, and a clear one for when the form is reset. Then add the following code to the Custom Format script of the field. The code will use the value of the field to swap the button icons. The value of 50 is arbitrary. Set it to the number you need.

```
if (event.value != "") {
    if (event.value <= 50) {
        this.getField("graphic").buttonSetIcon(this.getField("passed").buttonGetIcon());
    }
    else {
        this.getField("graphic").buttonSetIcon(this.getField("failed").buttonGetIcon());
    }
}
else {
    this.getField("graphic").buttonSetIcon(this.getField("clear").buttonGetIcon());
}
```

You can download a working example from [here](https://practicalpdf.com/techniques/pdf/check-if-valid.pdf).